# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value, but there is some value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, option-type

I am trying to get do a GET request, and save the following results from into NSMutuableArray. Then I am trying to load the following data I got into a tableview, but I am getting an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value" whenever I try to configure the number of rows.

```
var dataArray:NSMutableArray?

Alamofire.request(.GET, "SOMERANDOMWEBSITE") .responseJSON { response in
        // using if-let syntax to save json into our NSMutuableArray
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            self.dataArray = JSON as? NSMutableArray
        }
    }
```

When i try to configure the number of rows:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return self.dataArray.count
}
```

It gives me an error: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value". But what's strange is that when I create a random button to see if the .count is indeed nil:

```
    @IBAction func function(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(self.dataArray?.count)
}
```

it returns me with Optional(2) instead of nil. Any ideas?

Comment: What is response.result.value set as after your web call?

Answer (score 3):

You made your array an Optional. We can see that here:

```
print(self.dataArray?.count)
```

So until it's populated in Alamofire's closure (the network request happens in the background), it is nil.

You quote:

```
return self.dataArray.count
```

but actually you probably have done

```
return self.dataArray!.count
```

This is why it crashes.

So you have to declare another option for count for when it's nil. A solution could be to safely unwrap the array then return the count or return a default value:

```
if let array = self.dataArray {
    return array.count
}
return 0
```

This same logic can be expressed in a single line, as @brian-nickel notes in the comments:

```
return self.dataArray?.count ?? 0
```

Also, as stated by @vadian in the comments, absolutely, an Optional array makes little sense here, it would be better to just have a non-optional empty array from the beginning.

Comment: Similarly, it could be `return self.dataArray?.count ?? 0`

Comment: I've added the shorthand alternative to the answer, it was a good idea. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No offense, but an optional data source array is very bad practice.

Comment: @vadian Absolutely. I also thought about that and I just added it to the answer as it is indeed a good idea to remind OP about it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the method of declaring another option for count when it's nil, but it always returned me 0. Then I tried switching to having an non-optional empty array from the beginning, but got the same problem of being returned an 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's not strange, it's asynchronous.

Initially you declare `dataArray` as optional (aka `nil`) but don't initialize it.

The first attempt to update the table view fails (crashes) because calling `count` on `nil` is a bad idea.

Meanwhile the asynchronous request method returns the data and assigns it to `dataArray` which has now an (optional) value.

That's why you get a result in `function`.

Solution is to declare and initialize the array as non-optional Swift type.

```
var dataArray = [AnyObject]()
```

Probably there is a more specific type than `AnyObject`

and assign the returned data accordingly casting the result to the "better" type.

---

Basically declaring table view data source arrays as optional is absurd since your table **view** is always non-optional.